# Joining two text after explode

Tags: php

```
$string = 'some_name@somedomain.com';
$res = explode('@', $string);
$ext = '.jpg';
$newString = $res . $ext;
```

my result turn out to be only .jpg when I expected some_name.jpg

Comment: [Your result is not just .jpg but Array.jpg.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BD7I0V) because `explode` returns an array. You want `$res[0]`.

Comment: Initially it was Array.jpg. my string was empty because I forgot to set it as my post parameter in my Java. Lol. Solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explode` returns an *array*, so you'll need to pick an element:

```
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

Comment: Im sorry, the code work, I did some mistake on the other part of the code! Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

You need to index into the array you're creating with `explode()`:

```
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

Answer (score 3):

`$res` contains an array, use this:

```
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should concatenate $res[0] and $ext:

```
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

Answer (score 2):

After exploding the string it convert into array :

`$res` is an array. So try

```
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

and you can check this by  `print_r($res);` and use that index which you want.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to join an array with a string. Choose an element and concatenate.

```
$string = 'blablabla@gmail.com';
$result = explode('@', $string);
$ext = '.jpg';
$newString = $result[0] . $ext;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$res` is an array. You need `$res[0]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'some_name@somedomain.com';
$res = explode('@', $string);
$ext = '.jpg';
$newString = $res[0] . $ext;
```

Answer (score 1):

`$newString = $res[0] . $ext;`